# Print a Grid in Python without any package importing

Tags: python, grid

To create the print_grid function, my idea is to declare a string as empty and adding two types of of other strings("+---" and "| ") to it. Finally i want to print it out. But I am not sure how to print alternate grid lines and char line. Would you please give me some hints along with following code modification?

```
def print_grid(puzzle: str) -> None
    """
    Displays the puzzle in a user-friendly format
    Examples of calling print grid:
    >>> print_grid("nevagonagiveu up")
    +---+---+---+---+
    | n | e | v | a |
    +---+---+---+---+
    | g | o | n | a |
    +---+---+---+---+
    | g | i | v | e |
    +---+---+---+---+
    | u | | u | p |
    +---+---+---+---+

    Parameters:
        puzzle (str): the selected puzzle words in a string.
        
    Returns:
        none

    """
    
    p = len(puzzle)/sqrt(len(puzzle))
    result1 = ""
    for i in range(p):
        result1 += "+---"
    return result1    
    result2 =""    
    for j in range (p):
        result2 += "| "
    return result2
    print
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with the following code:

```
import math

def print_grid(puzzle):
    width = int(len(puzzle) / math.sqrt(len(puzzle)))

    decorator = "+"
    for i in range(width):
        decorator += "---+"
    print(decorator)
    for j in range(0, len(puzzle), width):
        line = "|"
        for k in range(j, j + width):
            line += f" {puzzle[k]} |"
        print(line)
        print(decorator)
```

It does not work for all string lengths, but your question was about printing alternate lines, so I am posting it as a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the required job. (I imported math lib for **ceil()** but if that is not allowed too then you can put a simple condition for getting ceiling of the decimal):

```
import math

def print_grid(puzzle):
    list1=[' ']+[' '+item+' |' for item in puzzle]
    length=len(puzzle)
    iter_=math.ceil(math.sqrt(length))

    fallout=(iter_)**2-length
    if fallout:
        list1=list1+['   |']*fallout

    for i in range(0,length,iter_):
        print('+---'*(iter_)+'+')
        pp=''.join(list1[i+1:i+iter_+1])
        print('|'+ pp)
    
    print('+---'*(iter_)+'+')
    
print_grid('nevagonagiveu up')

Output:
+---+---+---+---+
| n | e | v | a |
+---+---+---+---+
| g | o | n | a |
+---+---+---+---+
| g | i | v | e |
+---+---+---+---+
| u |   | u | p |
+---+---+---+---+
```